RefCell being set to None when moved to a thread
I followed this post and I was able to successfully the channels and global resources. However, when I invoke the sender thread it says that the RefCell that contains my sender and global resource is set to None.
This is in spite of the fact that I just initialized the RefCell with a Some. What could be causing this issue to occur?
use std::{cell::RefCell, sync::mpsc, time::Duration};

use gtk::{
    self,
    gio::ListStore,
    glib::{self, clone},
    prelude::*,
    Application, ApplicationWindow, Button, GridView, ListItem, SignalListItemFactory,
    SingleSelection, Text, TextBuffer,
};

const APP_ID: &str = "org.Waytrogen.Waytrogen";

thread_local! {
    static GLOBAL_BUFFER: RefCell<Option<(TextBuffer, mpsc::Sender<usize>)>> = const { RefCell::new(None) };
}

thread_local! {
    static GLOBAL_STORE: RefCell<Option<(ListStore, mpsc::Receiver<usize>)>> = const { RefCell::new(None) };
}

fn main() -> glib::ExitCode {
    // Create a new application
    let app = Application::builder().application_id(APP_ID).build();

    app.connect_activate(|app| {
        build_ui(app);
    });

    // Run the application
    app.run()
}

fn build_ui(app: &Application) {
    let window = ApplicationWindow::builder()
        .application(app)
        .title("Waytrogen")
        .build();

    window.present();

    let nums_store = ListStore::new::<Text>();

    let selection = SingleSelection::new(Some(nums_store.clone()));
    let nums_signal_list_item_factory = SignalListItemFactory::new();
    nums_signal_list_item_factory.connect_setup(clone!(move |_factory, item| {
        let item = item.downcast_ref::<ListItem>().unwrap();
        let button = Button::builder()
            .vexpand(true)
            .hexpand(true)
            .can_shrink(true)
            .build();
        item.set_child(Some(&button));
    }));

    let folder_path_buffer = TextBuffer::builder().build();
    folder_path_buffer.set_text("1");


    let (tx_wallpaper_folder, rx_wallpaper_folder) = mpsc::channel();
    GLOBAL_BUFFER.with(|global| {
        *global.borrow_mut() = Some((folder_path_buffer.clone(), tx_wallpaper_folder));
    });

    GLOBAL_STORE.with(|global| {
        *global.borrow_mut() = Some((nums_store.clone(), rx_wallpaper_folder));
    });
    transmit();
    let grid = GridView::builder()
        .model(&selection)
        .factory(&nums_signal_list_item_factory)
        .build();
    window.set_child(Some(&grid));
}

fn transmit() {
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        GLOBAL_BUFFER.with(|global| {
            if let Some((buffer, tx)) = &*global.borrow() {
                tx.send(
                    buffer
                        .text(&buffer.start_iter(), &buffer.end_iter(), false)
                        .to_string()
                        .parse::<usize>()
                        .unwrap(),
                )
                .unwrap();
                glib::timeout_add(Duration::from_millis(10), || {
                    receive();
                    glib::ControlFlow::Continue
                });
            }
        })
    });
}

fn receive() {
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        GLOBAL_STORE.with(|global| {
            if let Some((store, x)) = &*global.borrow() {
                store.append(&Text::builder().text(x.recv().unwrap().to_string()).build());
            }
        })
    });
}

I checked the value of the ref cell using the log crate and verified that before spawning the thread the RefCell had a some variant. I was expecting it to transmit and received as per the guidance of the post mentioned above but it did not transmit anything since the guard clause correctly prevented the None variant to be executed.

You're using a thread local, of course on different threads it will have different values.

Be aware that in the original post, the thread never accesses the thread_local. It is only being used inside of glib::source::idle_add, which then executes it inside of the UI thread.

Basically, in the original post it gets used to store UI internal state, not to communicate with the UI.
